How to Sync Visual Studio Code file automatically to Amazon AWS S3 Bucket - Mac
After hours of struggling I cannot find the answer as to how I can automatically sync my .css file on my local Visual Studio Code to the Amazon Web Services S3 bucket I created. On every save, I would like it to also save on Amazon Web Services rather than constantly uploading the same file over and over again. I am extremely confused by the AWS CLI configuration. I need help. I am not a beginner to HTML/CSS but I am a beginner when it comes to configuring and syncing things.
I will not be offended if you explain this to me like a child, in fact I would really appreciate it. Thank you!
I tried the AWS Visual Studio Code app, that didn't work. I could login with my user but couldn't create anything or access any files. I also tried looking into this page but I have no idea what it wants me to do.

The first step would be to get the AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI) working on your computer. It will allow you to store your AWS credentials in a configuration file that will be used by VSC. If you have the AWS CLI installed, run aws configure from a Terminal window and provide it the Access Key and Secret Key for your IAM User. If you are in a company, an Administrator can give them to you. If you have your own AWS Account, you should create an IAM User in the IAM management console (not IAM Identity Center). You can then create the credentials there.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Use aws sync command whenever code needs to be uploaded into s3 bucket. Following command synchronies the local folder to s3 bucket,
aws s3 sync . s3://bucket-name/

legend:

. => indicates current directory.
s3 path => indicates location where the code needs to be uploaded.

Prerequisite:

Install AWS CLI: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html
Create IAM security credentials - https://medium.com/@deepamathan/step-by-step-guide-to-generate-aws-security-credentials-8c0b433e5de6#0a81
Execute command - aws configure and enter following details,
a. AWS Access Key ID: Updated this from credentials got from step 2.
b. AWS Secret Access Key: Updated this from credentials got from step 2.
c. region: Region where bucket resides
b. output: json


I am able to upload the file I would like into the bucket successfully with terminal, but whenever I want to use the sync command it syncs everything on my Desktop to S3. I would only like to sync one file. I'm almost there...

Then use cp, as in aws s3 cp filename.html s3://example/filename.html

I guess this works, but do I have to run this command any time I want the file to change? Ideally, I would just save my code in Visual Studio Code and it would automatically refresh onto AWS. Is that possible? That's what I assumed sync meant.
